# Enabling http and https to port 8000

Tags: nginx

I'm having trouble of being able to access http://example.com:8000 and https://example.com:8000 but I can't seem to get them both work. This will serve as our backend and will API requests all through out. I want to either

- open http://example.com:8000 and https://example.com:8000 open for API request

or

- redirect from http to https redirect including the CORS authentication and and everything so the client can still get the return even with the redirect

This is my configuration so far

```
server {
    listen 8000 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/example.com.key;
    charset utf-8;


    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://ghost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    error_page  497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different ports:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    listen 8443 ssl;

    # other directives
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I need it to be both 8000 not another. Is it still possible?

Comment: What about redirecting but including the dears like CORS or authentication header?

Comment: Add ssl on; and error_page 497 $request_uri; to your server definition.
See this answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/47876/handling-http-and-https-requests-using-a-single-port-with-nginx/664936

Comment: Wow it worked! both ssl and non-ssl can now be accessed. But what about the redirect?